# Combine 2 functions and 2 procedures into a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've currently got 2 functions and 2 procedures that run fine. To achieve what the program is supposed to do, I execute procedure 1 and then procedure 2, which in turn will reference the functions as it executes. I now need to combine everything into a single package with an entry module to run. Each procedure/function has its own variables so I am not sure where to declare everything (whether in the intro or body).

For the purposes of explaining, I have included what I've tried so far (that didn't work). Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package myPackage AS

FUNCTION calculateHoliday (p_day in date);

FUNCTION calculateAvg (p_dayname in varchar2, p_timeinterval in number);

PROCEDURE loopHalfHourValues;

PROCEDURE generateForecast;

END myPackage;


PACKAGE BODY entryModule AS

  ...paste entirety of procedures and functions...

END entryModule;
```

Comment: You shouldn't include `CREATE OR REPLACE` inside the package spec. Your function declarations are missing closing semicolons (;). Apart from that... "didn't work" is not an error message!

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code above with what I've now tried and still getting an error. Unfortunately, sqldeveloper doesn't tell me anything other than it has errors and to check the compiler log, which has nothing.

Comment: @Peter So you have 2 procedures and 2 functions, and you need an "entry module". Do you mean by this something like a main procedure? Because if you do, then you need one more procedure main, defined in the package. As for where to define the variables it depends if you need or not global variables

Comment: please correct that typo at the package declaration! `create or replace package mypackage` (see [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_package.htm)). Not sure if [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) can handle plsql, but maybe you should give it a try ...

Comment: Have you removed the `create or replace` parts from the package body as well? Yhe package and package body have to have the same name, not sure if that's another typo. Have both the spec and body built (implying you have a `/` between them), and which errored? This would be much easier if you'd show the error - I have no idea why you still haven't done so.

Comment: Yes, I had removed that. Sorry guys, like I mentioned, the sqldeveoper program is not logging errors properly.

Comment: sqldeveloper is just an IDE, logging errors is not its job. Showing compilation errors can be done by adding `SHOW ERRORS` at the end of your script.

Answer (score 2):

**Function has to return something!**

```
/* package specification */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE myPackage AS

    /* public variables here */
    g_variable_no NUMBER; 
    g_variable_ch VARCHAR2(4000); 

    /* public procedures and functions here */
    FUNCTION  calculateHoliday(p_day IN DATE) RETURN return_type;
    FUNCTION  calculateAvg(p_dayname IN VARCHAR2, p_timeinterval IN NUMBER) RETURN return_type;
    PROCEDURE loopHalfHourValues;
    PROCEDURE generateForecast;

END myPackage;

/* package specification */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY entryModule AS

    /* private variables here */
    l_variable_no NUMBER; 
    l_variable_ch VARCHAR2(4000); 

    FUNCTION calculateHoliday(p_day IN DATE) RETURN return_type
    AS
        l_return return_type;
    BEGIN
        RETURN return_type;
    END;

    FUNCTION  calculateAvg(p_dayname IN VARCHAR2, p_timeinterval IN NUMBER) RETURN return_type
    AS
        l_return return_type;
    BEGIN
        RETURN return_type;
    END;

    PROCEDURE loopHalfHourValues
    AS
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END;

    PROCEDURE generateForecast
    AS
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END;

END entryModule;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "myPackage" AS

FUNCTION calculateHoliday (p_day in date);

FUNCTION calculateAvg (p_dayname in varchar2, p_timeinterval in number);

PROCEDURE loopHalfHourValues;

PROCEDURE generateForecast;

PROCEDURE main;

END myPackage;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "myPackage" AS

   -- declare global variables

   FUNCTION calculateHoliday (p_day in date)
    ....
   end calculateHoliday;

   FUNCTION calculateAvg (p_dayname in varchar2, p_timeinterval in number)
   ....
   end calculateAvg;

   PROCEDURE loopHalfHourValues is
   ...
   end loopHalfHourValues;

   PROCEDURE generateForecast is
   ...
   end generateForecast;

   PROCEDURE main is
   ...                   -- entry point call the procedures/functionns
   end main ;


END myPackage;
```

Answer (score 0):

your package spec and body are different identifiers use same identifiers for package spec and body

create or replace package myPackage AS --- spec

create or replace package Body myPackage AS --- body

make entrymodule a separate package to call or a separate procedure , in this case i dont think it is required.